# Liquibase rollback - is it useful?

Tags: liquibase

I'm wondering in which situation rollbacks in Liquibase could be useful. In most cases handling liquibase rollback push developers to write some additional changesets. But what is a real value of that ? It's not easy to always write rollbacks in filled database. I only see one value of that feature - when we want to back to some previous version we can invoke rollback. But it's easier to just drop database and call Liquibase to build a database once again. It's short operation.  Could anyone tell me some real cases where you use this feature ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, "it's *infinitely* useful", but to give you a synopsis of how or why it's useful, we need to explain a few other concepts.

One can liken Liquibase to a system like [Active Record](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord), which, alongside it being an ORM solution chiefly for Rails, is also famous for allowing its developers to migrate and roll back the changes.  It even keeps track of the change sets it's run already so that one can at a glance identify what's been run before and what hasn't.

Now, the migration part is simple.  You want to be able to migrate changes so that you can actually improve the database, incrementally, over time, with a record of what's changed.  That is, just in case something *does* break and you do have to go back to fix it.  This is where the rollback functionality comes in; if a schema change turns out to be malperformant, causes data loss, or is broken for that database, rolling back the schema and restoring the data to its original state (likely through backups) is critical to helping maintain the stability of the system.

To your suggestion:

> But it's easier to just drop database and call Liquibase to build a database once again.

You ***cannot*** do that in a production environment.  Many developers, engineers, and managers would liken dropping the production database to a fireable offense.  Especially when there are potentially hundreds or thousands of connections to your site that depend on that data being there in some state.

The rollback will help you mitigate the damage or misconfiguration done by one schema change, and it will allow you the chance to reduce the likelihood of impact to other systems or other users.

Comment: I asked about this,because in my team we have some different usage of Liquibase. We use it only during development, and we produce sql files from changesets. That is because we are a part of some other project and for consistency we need to just produce sql files which are used in some script which produce database. We are not forced to care about rollbacks to move back to previous version. This is the reason why I started to think if it's really necessary in my project to still handle rollback writing